# DataRelation Equivalent in Subsonic 3

Tags: subsonic

I have some code that returns data from a self referencing table (ID,ParentID) into a DataSet. It then adds a DataRelation to the DataSet and writes the DataSet to XML.  This write the XML as the expected hierarchy.

How do I do this in Subsonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not continue to use the same code? Read the table using subsonic if you like, put it into a data set. There is no feature in subsonic to write xml for you.